How to create a custom date and time input in vue3 composition
I'm creating a reservation form in vue3 composition API, I've been able to set the date input to start from the current day, so any other day before the current day is invalid and cannot be selected. I've been trying to do the same thing in the time input but it doesn't seem to work.
I can't set max and min time. Also, I want the times to become invalid and the user cannot select a specific time after another user has already selected that time.
Here's a vue playground demo of the code I currently have Vue Playground 


The min and max attributes are working. They don't prevent the user from choosing anything between 0 and 24, but when Submitting the form, the input will display a warning message like "Value must be 8 or later". See the type="time" documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

In updateAvailableTimes, the startTime and endTime are being compared directly, but they are Date objects and the comparison might not work as expected due to the milliseconds part of the Date object. Instead, you should compare the hours and minutes part of the Date objects.


Here is a working solution, hope it helps:
<script setup>
import { reactive, ref } from 'vue'

const formData = reactive({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    date: '',
    phone: '',
    time: ''
})

const availableTimes = ref([])
const minTime = ref('08:00') // 8am
const maxTime = ref('22:00') // 10pm

const selectedDates = ref([]) // Store selected dates
const selectedTimes = ref([]) // Store selected times

const updateAvailableTimes = () => {
    let startTime = new Date(`2022-01-01T${minTime.value}`)
    let endTime = new Date(`2024-01-01T${maxTime.value}`)
    const timeInterval = 30 // minutes

    availableTimes.value = []

    while (startTime.getTime() <= endTime.getTime()) {
        availableTimes.value.push(startTime.toISOString().slice(11,16)) // Get time in HH:MM format
        startTime.setMinutes(startTime.getMinutes() + timeInterval)
    }
}

updateAvailableTimes()

const removeSelectedDate = () => {
    if (selectedDates.value.includes(formData.date)) {
        alert('This date is already taken. Please select a different date')
    } else {
        selectedDates.value.push(formData.date)
    }
}

const removeSelectedTime = () => {
    if (selectedTimes.value.includes(formData.time)) {
        alert('This time is already taken. Please select a different time')
    } else if (!availableTimes.value.includes(formData.time)) {
        alert('This time is not available. Please select a different time')
    } else {
        selectedTimes.value.push(formData.time)
    }
}

const currentDate = ref(new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)) // Get current date in YYYY-MM-DD format

const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log('Form submitted:', formData)
    formData.date = ''
    formData.time = ''
}
</script>

